# How many development ORG for Team

Tags: developer-org

Salesforce is different so want advice from expert

We have team of 6-8 developers we want to set up development ORG for each one before we take that route want opinion from expert what is best practice

1. Every developer has his own ORG o
2. For Team we have single ORG which makes saves the time to setup ,

Comment: Different ORG for each developer doesn't make sense. until unless they are working upon independent modules. General approach is to have dev org-> sandbox for testing-> full copy sandbox->production org. Also you can read about [Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_dev_model) which is a great tool for best code practices.

Comment: This is a really broad question and it also has a lot to do with your specific development process, but I'm going to respectfully disagree with @Mr.Frodo - there are advantages to allocating each developer their own Developer sandbox, pushing up to a single Integration sandbox. However, for new development, evaluating SFDX is a good option.

Comment: You might want to have a look on a question I answered earlier.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218918/how-many-developers-should-work-on-same-developer-pro-sandbox-without-impacting/218923?noredirect=1#comment331755_218923

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old (pre SalesforceDX) best practice was:

- Individual sandboxes for each developer to work in(developer sandbox type)
- QA/Integration/Staging sandbox(es) to integrate/validate everyone's work (partial copy or full copy sandbox type)
- Some form of version control (git, mercurial, subversion, etc...)

Current best practice (Spring/Summer '18) here is:

- Use Salesforce DX
- Some form of version control (git, mercurial, subversion, etc...)
- Do development work in a scratch org
- QA/Integration/Staging sandbox(es) for integration/validation (partial or full copy)
- Some CI/CD (Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery) tool to automate running tests and deployments

Either way, the general idea behind this is that you want to have something to track history of your code base (Salesforce alone is wholly inadequate here). Version control makes it easier to revert bad changes (if, for example, you use tags in git) and gives you the chance to see if developers are stepping on each others' toes (trying to change the same code, or undo others' changes).

You perform development work in a fairly isolated sandbox. You can have people share sandboxes, but if you're making use of version control, you shouldn't need to (work off of the same branch, pull the latest version, and deploy to your individual sandbox).

After development is finished, you integrate everyone's changes into a single org and run tests to make sure that nothing breaks when combining everyone's components. With pretty much all but the smallest of teams, you'll need the aid of some "diff" tool to help identify what has been changed (to avoid stepping on other developers' toes). Version control can take care of this for you, but if you aren't using version control, there are tools like kdiff, Meld, P4Merge (from Perforce), etc...

Then, the changes are "promoted" to QA/UAT (User Acceptance Testing) so that your users can experience/be trained on the changes.

Finally, your changes are promoted to a staging environment, and then when everything is ready you deploy to production.

Some of the steps here may be consolidated. For a number of years, I was the only one at my company dedicated to working on Salesforce (with my boss doing some occasional development work). Integration and Staging weren't really big concerns with our team of 2, so our flow was Developer sandbox -> QA sandbox -> production.

Using Salesforce DX and version control makes it easy (or at least a lot easier than it used to be) to perform "Continuous Integration", where changes are combined and tests are run on a regular basis. The goal is to not "break the build". A build is "broken" if your code doesn't compile, or if unit tests fail. Doing this regularly (as opposed to all at once, towards the end of a project) helps identify issues earlier (when they are hopefully easier to fix). I don't necessarily think this obsoletes a final integration step, and it generally makes integration a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single dev org so that you will have to do the setup at one place only and this approach is good for expanding the configurations as well as you will just have to do it at one place. Once the dev org is ready you can assign sandbox to individual developer.

So like Mr Frodo said the approach should be going like this
dev org-> sandbox for testing-> full copy sandbox->production org

Comment: But when it is single ORG if it is screwed by some one hole team will face problem.

Comment: The individual team member can use their own sandbox.In that way they can work independently.When they feel they need to push their changes to main org they can do it with the help of change sets