# How many developers should work on same developer pro sandbox without impacting performance?

Tags: sandbox, developer-console

Is there a figure on number of developers should work on same Developer Pro sandbox? I see a lot of performance issue and environment is very unresponsive when multiple developers (~5) have enabled debug logs. It becomes impossible to use developer console. It doesn't respond on clicks, navigation and throws no response from server errors.
Is there any best practice to follow here?

Answer (score 2):

Coding on Developer-Pro Sandbox you are asking for trouble in the first place. Developer-Pro sandbox is supposed to be UAT-QA and not your usual development environment.

Having a single sandbox where multiple developer's code is like playing a devils advocate where anyone can overwrite someone else's code and there is no tracking and historical code change trends. It can get ugly even before you think about migrating.

A developer should have their own Sandbox where they work and test their code peacefully. Once they are sure they can commit in Code Versioning System and move to Developer-PRO(QA or UAT).

[image]

The problems you mentioned is the reason salesforce provides 100's of sandboxes so that each dev can have at least 1 sandbox and can work/test peacefully without facing intermittent issues from other devs working on their functionality.

You might be interested in looking into Salesforce DX which introduces scratch orgs which have life of 7 days that devs can use to work over the week and get going.

SFDX: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/sfdx_get_started

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=0

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_development_lifecycle.pdf

Comment: +1, and everything you say here goes double if developers are trying to share a Dev Pro sandbox *while using Developer Console* instead of an offline IDE.

Comment: Thanks Pranay for replying but my issue is not on looking for alternative. I wanted to see if there are any guidelines on how many parallel debug logs. we using dev pro because dev org can't support storage for our test data.

Comment: 100mb is more that enough for a single dev. You dont test on all data in one go. I know data creation is bit tricky but thats what best practices state.  That been said, There are no guidelines for what you are looking for. There were no studies for this behaviour . You might have to raise a case with SF for this.

Comment: Even 1GB is not enough in our case unfortunately. Not sure if you ever worked on any commerce projects where you can't really do development as you don't have data. We have to treat data as metadata to make our logic work but storage limit applies to it. I believe this should be the case with many of such projects. Limit of 5 dev pro sandboxes makes it worse.